# How to create new oracle database with same structure as another database but without data?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, oracle-apps

I wanted to create a database with the same structure as another database but without restoring data.

Comment: use `expdp` with only DDL option and then use `impdp`.

Answer (score -1):

Is good idea use Database Configuration Assistant.

Use dbca (Templates )

1. Create a template for existing database.
2. Create a database from template